# Purge history for a pushed confidential data in remote origin?

Tags: git

A while ago, we've pushed some `app.settings` files containing sensitive data such as connection strings.

That was long time ago and since then we've removed (by pushing new versions) which don't contains the sensitive data.

However , If someone will try to see `app.settings`'s history - he will see the connection strings.

**Question**

How can I make the passwords not to be there even with history lookup.
Also- I don't want to see that `connection strings` has been removed compared the one commit after.

Clarification: I don't want to remove the file , only few lines.

Visualization:

2017 - commit - `connectionstring=***,***`
2018 - commit -  removed `connectionstring=***,***`
2019 - histroy of commits , I will see the sensitive data.

I want to delete 2017's sensitive lines and I dont want to see that 2018 now has few lines less (the sensitive data , will be displayed in diff imho) .

Comment: You will have to rewrite the entire history to remove the information everywhere.  This is no easy task, and even if you do it, there is still always the chance that some other user could still have the old version on their machine.  Best advice here is: don't let it happen in the first place.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository

Comment: @hyde it will remove _file_ rather than _few lines_. right ?

Comment: And note that *everybody* who has a clone  needs to for example get a fresh clone and erase the old one if you want the sensitive data really gone. You can't change local branches of other clones from upstream.

Comment: @hyde Sure. make sense. thanks

Comment: I used that linked tool years ago to remove a disk image. Not sure how to go about replacing a file with modified version, but if you can remove a file, it should be possible to add a file too... Oh, and make sure you have good backups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic case described in GitHub help page "[Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)".
As commented, it will involve rewriting, and then force pushing the entire history of the Git repository.

But considering the distributed nature of Git, other might already have cloned the (old version of) your repository.

Which means the *main* advice is: first and foremost, change your connection credentials now.
**Make sure that old versioned sensitive data is no longer sensitive**.

*Then* you can worry about cleaning up the history of your repository.